# Grub boots to rescue mode after restoring windows

Tags: boot

So my asus PC had linux and windows on it with GRUB as its loader but I decided to reinstall windows to the whole hd.Everything worked fine until it rebooted post-restore to GRUB rescue command propt that reads"unknonwn filesystem".Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Windows boot code to MBR.

In Windows 7,8 you can use on recovery command prompt:

```
bootsect /nt60 all /mbr
```

to write Windows boot code to partition and master boot record(MBR).